# How save a variable from session and get when session is null?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I Write into a session user login. I need to get user login on server side page when a session is dropped.
I try:

```
 private string currentUserLogin;
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {   
      if (!IsPostBack)
      {
          if (HttpContext.Current.Session["curUserRole"] == null)
          {
               // try to get a "currentUserLogin" varialbe, but it null!
          }
          else
          {
               currentUserLogin = HttpContext.Current.Session["curUserLogin"].ToString();                   
          }
      }
 }
```

Comment: what do you mean when session is dropped? are you trying to access session after session timeout?

Comment: Where is the `HttpContext.Current.Session["curUserRole"] = someValue;` in your code? Do you set the session value anywhere?

Comment: I to use variable that was in session after session timeout

Comment: Data write into session when user login on site

Comment: Is there a reason you aren't just making the session timeout longer so that you don't *need* to access it after it is expired?

Comment: You can't persist the value in `currentUserLogin` variable, as each time you try to access the page it is going to get initialized.

Comment: As @Blast_dan suggests, if you are trying to access session variables when the session has timed out you'll always get nothing back because it has been removed. Also you are using two different session variables names, is this code sample correct?

Answer (score 1):

Store the information from the session into cookie (with desired expiration time) & retrieve the value from cookie when session expires.

Comment: User Roles and User Logins are not for cookies, This stuff should be Database driven.
However you are right in saying it can't be session stored.

Answer (score 0):

In the Global.asax there is a SessionEnd event.   I use it to write to write to to a log file the userID and logoff date/time.

Comment: It should be pointed out that the `SessionEnd` event only works when your session store is in-memory, not when you are using a State Server or SQL Server